# How to convert CRSP date type into normal date type YYMMDD?

Tags: date, date-conversion

I am struggling with an issue of converting the date type of CRSP dataset into a normal date type such as YYMMDD. My CRSP dataset is downloaded as a SAS format but the date is represented by SAS integer number such as 7456.

Anyone know how to convert the SAS integer number into a normal date format YYMMDD? I will be very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS stores dates as the number of days using 0 to mean 1960-01-01. So depending on what system you are using you just would need to add 7,456 days to the value your system uses to store January 1, 1960.

```
data _null_;
  input date ;
  put date comma7. +1 date date9. +1 date yymmdd10. ;
cards;
0
7456
;


    0 01JAN1960 1960-01-01
7,456 31MAY1980 1980-05-31
```